# iPhone - entering equations

Tags: iphone, math, symbolic-math

I've been researching this topic for a few weeks now, but I'm still unsure as to what is the "best" way to approach this problem.
I am designing an app, and part of the input involves entering an equation (ie mathematical function). I'm not looking for anything super complicated; it's single-variable, at least for now. 
What is the best way to approach entry and parsing? Is there a parser that is very good for this? What about a graphical approach such as dragging/selecting parts and assembling a function by its components? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use regular expressions to parse it out.
Check out NSRegularExpression and Google around for a regex that will parse out the equation into its different parts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your application extensible (for the future) you should read something about parser theory. There is a simple example on wikipedia ([here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_bison)) from which you can start. It uses flex (to generate the lexer) and bison (to generate the parser) which can be easily integrated with Objective-C code.

If that example is more than expected you can start with a more simple one from the bison manual ([here](http://www.gnu.org/s/bison/manual/bison.html#Rpcalc-Rules)).

Answer (score 0):

you can use mathml products like mathtype and maths magic.
for other products see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_editor)

If you want to use javascript for formatting that use [jqmath](http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html)